# Saving record while accepting server updates

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When adding or updating a record via ember-data's `save()` method it successfully sends the request to the server. The server then returns -- as part of its success message -- the same object back but with some additional information included (things like the last_updated stamp but also potentially other attributes). I thought this was the norm and that this returned structure would be incorporated back into the local ember version of the model but it appears not.

I could do a reload() after saving but that would add an entirely unnecessary call to the backend. If I forced the the changes myself into the local cache it would then move into a "dirty" status which of course is not really the case. Surely there must be an elegant way of handling this relatively simple scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
It may be due to the fact that you've created your record in lower case:

```
store.createRecord('client')
```

vs

```
store.createRecord('Client')
```

Comment: interesting. worth a check. let me give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the "additional information" as DS.attr in the original model , then the response would set these properties and you would not need to reload or make any change locally.

Comment: All of these fields are declared in the model and what you're describing is what I would have expected but not what I'm observing. I'll take another look at this to see if maybe I'm doing anything wrong. Do you have examples where this is working for you?